# Android building: JarJar can't find or load main class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build AOSP from source (With a few modifications) but my build stops with

```
[  0% 1/35196] JarJar: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/conscrypt_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "java -jar out/host/linux-x86/framework/jarjar.jar process external/conscrypt/jarjar-rules.txt out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/conscrypt_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/conscrypt_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar"
Error: Could not find or load main class com.tonicsystems.jarjar.Main
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [build/core/ninja.mk:149: ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

and i can't get to fix it. My source is hosted [here](http://github.com/AOSPlusone) and the path of external/jarjar is the stock one on googlesource.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem until I realized that it's due to the wrong path where com.tonicsystems.jarjar.Main is located. At `~/android/system`, JarJar's com.tonicsystems.jarjar class is located in:

```
external/jarjar/src/main/com/tonicsystems
```

When it should be

```
external/jarjar/src/main/java/com/tonicsystems
```

Like it's source (from GitHub)

[src/main/java/com/tonicsystems/jarjar](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/tree/master/jarjar-command/src/main/java/com/tonicsystems/jarjar)

**P.S:** I had to **create** the `external/jarjar/src/main/java` directory and then move the source.

Comment: ie. `mkdir external/jarjar/src/main/java && mv external/jarjar/src/main/com external/jarjar/src/main/java/com`

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this with an AOSP fork (I think Qualcomm's tree) before - that was caused by the Makefile fragments that generate the file lists for the jar files not dealing properly with localized versions of the "sort" utility (causing removal of important class files in addition to the duplicates that were supposed to be removed).

I don't remember all the details or the proper fix, but the workaround that got me going initially was simply disabling localization while building.

```
rm -rf out
export LANG=C
export LC_ALL=C
export LC_COLLATE=C
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch whatever
make droidcore -j8
```

Answer (score 2):

What fixed this for me was something completely unrelated to `jarjar` itself.

I was building AOSP 7.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. The default `python` command on Ubuntu 20.04 points to `python3` [[1]](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default), but AOSP 7.1.1 builds using `python` (which is really python 2.7.5).

I updated my system with `sudo apt install python` which linked the `python` command to `python2` correctly instead of `python3`. After this, I built successfully.

AOSP is shipped with `python` under the `prebuilts/python` directory and I'm still confused as to why the build system doesn't point to that `python` version.

**Edit**

I had more trouble with adjusting my system to use the correct version of `python`, ultimately I had to add `python` and `python3` as alternatives.

1. `$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1`
2. `$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 2`
3. `$ sudo update-alternatives --config python`
4. Select `python2`